# Can't restore a VM from a disk backup in Azure

Tags: azure

I can't get my VM disk restored in Azure: it is only "converted" to the Storage Account linked to my VM.

Does anyone know how to get a VM fully restored from a Recovery Service Vault backup in Azure please?

Edit :
For additional precision, I made a simple Linux VM hosting a test website in order to experience Azure's backup and restore feature.
So once the test website was online, I waited for a backup job to be done.
Then I deliberately broke the test website inside the VM, and launched a disk restore.
Unfortunately, the restore did nothing to the VM. I checked on the jobs and restore was marked as "Successful", and a VM restart did nothing.
Anyway, I can find the "vhd" in the Conainer tab of the Storage Account. But I can't find a way to attach it to the VM...
Is the disk restoration feature even supposed to work like intended ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate a backed up restore of a virtual machine using Azure Site Recovery.

When you restore the virtual machine you have the option to select if you want to restore the disks or the virtual machine.

[image: Azure ASR - restore VM]

Selecting here to restore as a VM, will create the VM for you.

You can check that status of the restore by going to the jobs section of the machine in ASR.

[image: Azure ASR - restore tasks]

For reference, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms) page for more detailed instructions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Unfortunately, when I select to restore the disk and wait for the job to be done, the files inside the VM are not the same as those in the backup, and I don't see any other disk created or so.. Do you know how to fix this please ?

Answer (score 0):

This likely flies in the face of what Azure thinks it can do, but have you tried to create the VM first and then just restore your data? Other possible options are:

- The user you are logged in as does have the correct permissions to create a VM in that space as well as restore the data, yes?
- And you did select Recovery Service vaults in the portal, correct?
- check if the original VM had any special conditions, such as multiple NICs or a load balancer. Any custom VM configurations, including HUB licensing, will not be duplicated with the Create Virtual Machine option as it uses Quick Create. You will need to use PowerShell to attach the restore disks to your chosen VM configuration. You can get additional information on PowerShell and Azure backups [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-automation).
- And in the link that kim provided above, scroll down to the "Create a new VM from a restore point" section and review the options and notes for creating a new VM. You can get more information on ASR at [this page](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/asr-migration-draas-solution).